# Borders disappeared after fill cell color

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I did some fill color to my cells (white or gray) with the following code

```
$sheet->getStyle($cellFrom.":".$cellTo)->getFill()
->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB($colorEscala);
```

then when I'm about to save the .xlsx I want the borders to appear again so I did this

```
 $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'outline' => array(
                'allBorders' => array(
                   'style' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
                   'color' =>  \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_BLACK,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    $sheet->getStyle( $sheet->calculateWorksheetDimension() )
    ->applyFromArray($styleArray
    );
```

but nothing happens, the borders are still gone, any idea why borders aren't appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a bit confused on internet because I couldn't find the properly way to do this and they've changed with the time
I managed to fix this with the following code in case it helps someone

```
$styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allBorders' => array(
                'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

seems they changed allborders to allBorders
and style to borderStyle